# C# Add Formatted Html String to Docx

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, file, docx

I've been trying to insert a html string in part of a word document with search and replace for at least a week, but it is never formatted and I need it to be formatted.

I manage to get a document formatted from an html only if I create a new document with HttpContext.Response using a string builder but it doesn't have what I need. I have succeeded with Aspose, only it is not free, so I cannot continue with this option.

I searched through Stackoverflow and I can't find an answer that helps me, it's often people who say to go and read OpenXML but nobody gives an example that worked for them.

I feel like I'm close to succeeding, but there may be a concept that I don't know.

Could you please help me?

```
var file = FormWriter.TurnIntoBytes(filePath);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(file))
            {
                using (var report = DocX.Load(stream))
                {

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> element in Data)
                    {
                        if (element.Key == "X")
                        {
                            report.ReplaceText("[" + element.Key + "]", example.ToString());
                        }                        
                        else if (element.Key == "Y")
                        {
                            report.ReplaceText("[" + element.Key + "]", element.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            report.ReplaceText("[" + element.Key + "]", element.Value);
       
                    }

                    report.SaveAs(ms);
                    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", filePath);
                }
            }
```

Comment: please share your code, word is very finicky when it comes to html.

Comment: I just added an example